# Error al ejecutar el Array MQL4

Tags: c++, array

Tengo un array en MQL4 y declaro el tamaño, Ancho y Largo, pero al momento de ejecutar el codigo me da error

Quisiera tener un contador que me cuente cuantas variables del array tienen valor 0, para poder calcular hasta donde esta lleno

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                       Prueba.mq4 |
//|                                                      Jose Nieves |
//|                                                          Telgram |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property strict

 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

int ar[5][6]; // Matriz
int points;

void OnInit()
{
   
   arrayslocos();
   
}

void arrayslocos(){
   
      ar[0][0]= 879546;
      ar[1][0]= 455798;
      ar[1][1]= 2022;
      ar[1][2]= 12;   
      ar[1][3]= 2; 
      ar[1][4]= 15; 
      ar[1][5]= 45; 

      
      int Size=(ArraySize(ar)/6);
      
      
      
   for (int i = 0; i <= Size; i++)
   {

      
       if(ar[i][0] == 0){points = points + 1;}
      

          
   }

   printf(points);
           
}
```

Me dice que debo depurar line: 44 que es la que marco en rojo en el codigo

[image: Error MT4]

Comment: cambia la condición del `for` por `i<Size`

Comment: Gracias bro! te debo una! ya el codigo me ejecuta